# Only can print from specific program

Tags: printer, network-printer

My company want to print documents from

Any Microsoft Office 2010 Program (Word, One Note, Powerpoint etc.)

And prevent printing from other program.

I have no solution about this issue.

Comment: This is not possible, not from Windows, nor from printer settings.

Comment: I mean set up for users only print from office program.

Comment: Neither Windows nor the printer/driver can limit printing to specific programs.

Comment: Is it possible to disable print button in Excel or Word?

Comment: It is, but that is the opposite of what you want to do. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e880e5e-ca41-4fb3-b78b-01573b8048c2/is-it-possible-to-disable-words-save-or-print-functions?forum=vsto and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/enable-and-disable-the-print-event-in-excel-2003/d2c34add-9947-49ac-bce2-d08fe0b51da0?auth=1

Comment: Actually, it is very hard for me to follow your instruction in that website. I don't know how to use Visual Studio to do that. I just have a idea about disable Print in File Tab. Maybe it is impossible.

Comment: Without special macro tricks like that, it is indeed impossible. And remember, it's the opposite of what you want: you want to disable printing from everything except Word & Excel. That is completely impossible.